# error Back-off restarting failed container in nginx pod

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, dockerfile

simple use-case to deploy the nginx image using kubernetes

Dockerfile used to create the image. The "./build/" in the dockerfile COPY statement, is the output directory (npm run build) of reactjs code.Just static files in it.

```
FROM nginx
COPY ./build/ /usr/share/nginx/html/ 
RUN rm -f /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
CMD ["nginx"]
EXPOSE 80
```

**Why is this error in nginx deployment? error is "Back-off restarting failed container".** 
manually ran the container, but nginx is not running. I could start the nginx manually. Am I missing any configuration in the Dockerfile or in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf file? files are copied and available in [github](https://github.com/get2arun/logs/blob/master/nginx-Back-off-restarting-failed-container) path for reference.

```
root@desktop:~/github/nginx-app# docker run -it private.registry.corp/company-dev-poc/nginx-cms:001 bash
root@fc7ebd431ae2:/# service nginx status
[FAIL] nginx is not running ... failed!
```

Comment: You have `docker run ... bash`, it means you created a container from an image and had run a single `bash` process in it. What you probably need instead is to run without a command name

Comment: @zerkms - the image i'm using is created from Dockerfile that has "CMD ["nginx"]" in it. but when ran without command like "docker run -it private.registry/nginx-cms:001", this way, the container is exited immediately. how does this image get started with kubectl deployment?

Comment: If the container exists immediately - it means the `CMD` has quit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]`

Also, you do not need to specify the command. CMD and EXPOSE would be defined in the base image - nginx in this case. They need not be defined again.

Comment: thanks Palash Goel. Just figured this and made it work. copying the static files to root directory should serve the context, right?

Comment: Rest of the Dockerfile looks good, though it can be shortened.
Here, we use a custom image which already has config defined inside.
The Docker file is simpler then: FROM rivigotech/nginx:1.13.12-reconf
COPY dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html